# Не работает сохранение громкости музыки в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

В этой части кода я реализовал использование переменной (musicVolume, в нее записывается громкость) из другого скрипта (находится в объекте MusicPlayer, в него добавлен как компонент скрипт, в котором класс VolumeValue). Эту часть кода я добавил как событие On Click к кнопке UI в самом юнити. Тут же возникает первая проблема, что при нажатии на нее в консоль не выводится никакого текста.

```
public void Save()
{

    GameObject.Find("MusicPlayer");
     float volume = GetComponent<VolumeValue>().musicVolume;
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gromkost", volume);
     PlayerPrefs.Save();
    Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
}
```

В этой части кода реализована загрузка сохраненных данных при запуске. Опять таки, в консоль ничего не выводится.

```
void Awake()
{
    GameObject.Find("MusicPlayer");
    float volume = GetComponent<VolumeValue>().musicVolume;
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("load", volume);
    Debug.Log("Start");
}
```

В итоге никаких ошибок компилятор не выдает, но и ничего не сохраняется, код не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

если нужно, то вот код отвечающий за регулировку громкости ползунком и из которого берется переменная

```
public AudioSource audioSrc;
public float musicVolume = 1f;


void Start()
{
    audioSrc = GetComponent<AudioSource>(); 
}

void Update()
{
    audioSrc.volume = musicVolume;
}

public void SetVolume(float vol) 
{
    musicVolume = vol;
}
```

Comment: Странный вопрос, но что если вы забыли повесить скрипт на объект? Или объект/скрипт отключен? Это единственные варианты, почему может не срабатывать Awake? Более того, вы как-то странно используете `PlayerPrefs.GetInt`. Ведь он *возвращает* значение, значит нужно что-то типа `volume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("load");`, а второй параметр функции `GetFloat` - это лишь значение по умолчанию на случай, если ключа из первого аргумента не существует. А функция Save вообще реализована непонятно. Что такое первая строчка? Про что вторая? По моему, вы неправильно/совсем не понимаете систему объектов юнити

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, в юнити нахожусь полтора дня, в C# тоже не силен, понимаю теперь насколько глупые ошибки.

Comment: Вы не знаете, по какой причине может не выводиться сообщение в консоль при нажатии на  кнопку в функции Save? Скрипт добавлен.

Comment: "Вы не знаете, по какой причине может не выводиться сообщение в консоль при нажатии на кнопку в функции Save? Скрипт добавлен." - на каком-то этапе выполнения кода перед Debug.Log вы могли получить null или Null Reference Exception

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно поняли как работает Find.

```
public void Save()
{
     float volume = GameObject.Find("MusicPlayer").GetComponent<VolumeValue>().musicVolume;
     PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("gromkost", volume);
     PlayerPrefs.Save();
     Debug.Log("Game data saved!");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @LittleBob Если ответ помог, пожалуйста, нажмите на галочку слева от ответа.

Comment: По прежнему ничего не работает, но нажму)

Comment: @LittleBob - У меня не работает! - Что не работает? - Ничего не работает! - А надо что? - А надо, чтобы работало!

Comment: @LittleBob Галочка — знак того, что ответ помог. Если ответ не помог — не надо жмакать галочку, вед это в первую очередь не для вас, не для отвечающего, а для ДРУГИХ пользователей, который придут и есть ПРИНЯТЫЙ ответ, который РЕАЛЬНО помогает. Поэтому не надо принимать не помогший ответ